# Numpy array, how to replace values that satisfy a list of conditions?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` and I want to replace values that are not in the list `a = [1, 3, 5, ...]` with `0`.

I tried `x[x not in a] = 0` but I got the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Anyone know the proper way that doesn't require spelling out the conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a = np.array([1, 3, 5])
x[~np.isin(x,a)] = 0

### Output
>>> array([1, 0, 3, 0, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use numpy.where :

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a = np.array([1, 3, 5])
mask = np.isin(x, a)
x[mask] = 0
print(x)
>>> array([0, 2, 0, 4, 0])
```